# Symfony2 Biderectional Relationship finBy query

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many, query-builder, bidirectional-relation

I want to do a query  in a bidirectional relationship using both class fields my classes are:

```
class Branch {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var Company
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="branches")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_company", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, unique=false)
 * 
 */
private $idCompany;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="friendly_url", type="string", length=30, nullable=false, unique=true)
 */
private $friendlyUrl;

//...

}


class Company {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")  
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var Branch
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Branch", mappedBy="idCompany")
 */
private $branches;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="friendly_url", type="string", length=30, nullable=false, unique=true)
 */
private $friendlyUrl;

//...
 }
```

Now I need to do a query thats can filter the information by friendly urls

for example:

webpage.com/company_friendly_url/branch_friendlyurl

Im lossing because I dont know how to do the correct query Im trying with this, but it is now working.

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('AspersoftDirectorioBundle:Company')->findBy(
   array(
      'friendlyUrl' => $company_friendly_url, 
      'branches.friendlyUrl' => $branch_friendly_url
   )
);
```

somebody else have idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
$companies = $em->createQuery("SELECT c, b from AspersoftDirectorioBundle:Company c LEFT JOIN c.branches b with b.friendlyUrl = :branchFriendlyUrl where c.friendlyUrl = :companyFriendlyUrl")
                ->setParameter("branchFriendlyUrl", $branch_friendly_url)
                ->setParameter("companyFriendlyUrl", $company_friendly_url)
                ->getResult();
```

hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that by using `findBy` instead you need to create a join query through `createQueryBuilder`

```
$query = $em->getRepository('AspersoftDirectorioBundle:Company')
       ->createQueryBuilder('c')
       ->join('c.branches', 'b')
       ->where('c.friendlyUrl = :cfriendlyURL')
       ->andWhere('b.friendlyUrl = :bfriendlyURL')
       ->setParameter('cfriendlyURL', $company_friendly_url)
       ->setParameter('bfriendlyURL', $branch_friendly_url)
       ->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();
```